# Show sum of a column after every row html/javascript

Tags: javascript, mysql

I am working on a cash-book and the is a very complicated data structure. I can not sum date with respect to id or date as e.g there is an option available for the client to add backdate entries and there could be more than one entry on one date. I have to show remaining balance after every row. So is there any way in javascript to add up column up to every row. i am not good in javascript.

Thank you
[here is the desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CE96.png)

Comment: A sample of what you think the result should look like would be helpful.  Are you expecting an outstanding balance at the end of each unique date? Also, do you have a sample of the data you are taking in and the JavaScript you are using to get the current results?

Comment: Are you wanting to use jQuery or plain javascript?

Comment: I Attached another photo which shows the desired results. Yes, want to use javascript which does calculation on page level after retrieval of data.